# SQLAlchemy automap data and override some columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is it possible in SQLAlchemy to automap existing database tables into classes but override some some fields of some tables?

I'm pickling the MetaData object, since it takes some time, it contains all the tables, but then when I'm trying to override some objects, it raises an exception that MetaData object is not bound to an Engine or Connection.

```python
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Column, String, Integer
import os, pickle

class MetadataCache(object):
    def __init__(self, engine, schema):
        self.engine = engine
        self.schema = schema
        self.metadata = None

    @property
    def cache_name(self):
        final_name = '{0}.{1}.cache'.format(self.engine.url.database,
                                            self.schema)
        return final_name

    def get_or_create_metadata(self):

        if os.path.exists(self.cache_name):
            with open(self.cache_name, 'r') as cachefile:
                self.metadata = pickle.load(cachefile)
        else:
            self.metadata = MetaData()
            self.metadata.reflect(bind=self.engine, schema=self.schema)
            with open(self.cache_name, 'w') as cachefile:
                pickle.dump(self.metadata, cachefile)

        return self.metadata

engine = create_engine('...')
metadata = MetadataCache(engine, 'schemaname').get_or_create_metadata()
Base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String)

class Profile(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'profile'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    userid = Column('userid', ForeignKey('user.id'))

Base.prepare(reflect=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

The error is raised because the metadata owned by `Base` (that you pass to the `automap_base` constructor) is not bound to an engine, nor should it be. It just means you have to pass a bind to `Base.prepare`.

Also, since you're reflecting the metadata manually, you shouldn't tell `Base.prepare` to do so.

Change your final line to this:

```
Base.prepare(engine)
```

**Edit:** Of course, I was thinking about `Base.prepare` needing the engine to do the reflection, but since you're passing a pre-reflected `MetaData()`, you can just use:

```
Base.prepare()
```

**Edit:**

In reply to the comment below, note that you must pass `extend_existing=True` to the `Table`:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String)
```

Comment: The issue, at least as I understand it, is that we want to use just the pickled metadata without the engine (which was originally used to create the metadata) necessarily being available (perhaps because the database isn't available).  Can you think of a workaround that would allow that?

Comment: Actually I got mixed up thinking about the answer, engine doesn't need passed to `Base.prepare`, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: The example in the questions isn't actually self contained, so I created a self-contained version here: https://gist.github.com/jcrudy/fb30f079dfcf29fc6e3bd97b037eee1a.  When I run it (with your suggested change to the last line), I get sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'user' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.  In fact, the error occurs at the definition of the User class.

Comment: @jcrudy You need to do so in `__table_args__`, I've again edited my answer.

Comment: I think that was the missing piece!  Thank you.

Comment: @jcrudy: I've tried your gist (in the process of learning SQLAlchemy) and it doesn't seem to be working (or I'm misunderstanding something). After Base.prepare() I'm expecting Base.classes to be populated with "user" and "profile" classes, given that we've specified the primary keys.  However this is not the case for me. However if you instead add the primary key spec to the Metadata, it does work.  Here's a response gist that demonstrates this: https://gist.github.com/ByteJuggler/e61b6db6b91fd7185eb72fce3adc9e6f

Comment: @W.Prins classes you define manually aren't placed in `Base.classes`. Either you define the class yourself, or define a Table in the metadata and get the class from `Base.classes`.